# I want to Pivot data into a crosstab but need to exclude dummy data put in with 99s

Tags: t-sql

```
) PivotedTableSource
PIVOT
(
    SUM(AnswerNumberValue)
    FOR QuestionCode IN (
        [Item1], 
        [Item2], 
        [Item3], 
        [Item4]. . .
```

I need to replace AnswerNumberValue with a Null when AnswerNumberValue = 99

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`NULLIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) function:

EDIT:
Unfortunately, I was mistaken about being able to do the `NULLIF` within the `PIVOT` statement.  The only solution that I can see would be to handle this in the `SELECT` of the pivoted results:

```
SELECT
    NULLIF([Item1], 99) AS [Item1], 
    NULLIF([Item2], 99) AS [Item2], 
    NULLIF([Item3], 99) AS [Item3], 
    NULLIF([Item4], 99) AS [Item4]... 
(
    Your Source Query...
) PivotedTableSource
PIVOT
(
    SUM(AnswerNumberValue)
    FOR QuestionCode IN (
        [Item1], 
        [Item2], 
        [Item3], 
        [Item4]. . .
```

Comment: you had me confused because I was trying to solve it too and the NULLIF didn't work, so I was wondering what magic you had.

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks for pointing out that my first answer wouldn't work... I've updated the answer, but the new solution isn't as simple as I would have hoped.